# Mule Database port is not a valid value for 'integer'

Tags: mule

I am trying to configure database port according to properties file:

```
    <jdbc-ee:mysql-data-source name="MySQL_Data_Source" user="${DB.User}" password="${DB.Password}" transactionIsolation="UNSPECIFIED" host="${DB.Host}" port="${DB.Port}" database="${DB.Name}" doc:name="MySQL Data Source"/>
```

I am storing value for DB.User in a development.properties file

```
#Database Connection Properties
DB.Host=localhost
DB.Port = 3360
DB.Name=test
DB.User=root
DB.Password=test
```

I have configured location of .properties file in a property placeholder. The setup works fine for other parameters. mule.env is an environment parameter with 'development' as value.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/connections/${mule.env}.properties"/>
```

An error occurred

```
    Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 16 in XML document from URL [file:/D:/icoe/mulews/.mule/apps/filetodb/filetodb.xml] is invalid; 
    nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${DB.Port}' is not a valid value for 'integer'. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
```

How can the port be rewritten?

Thanks,

Comment: Edit your question to explain how you configure values for `DB.User`...

Comment: I have edited the question as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use placeholders for the port. If you need to use a port defined in a properties file, you would need to configure the datasource as a regular Spring bean instead of using the configuration element mysql-data-source.

Comment: Same issue I am facing, I have configured as <db:oracle-config name="Oracle" host="${db.host}" port="${db.port}"...> it works fine in windows environment, but not in mac. weird